# NSMutableDictionary not Setting Keys

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

All,

I'm sure I'm overlooking something, but I've been staring at this code for too long trying to figure out what's going on.

```
-(IBAction)continue:(id)sender
{
    //setters for the limits
    NSLog(@"Log ageUnder18: %@", ageUnder18.text);   //returns Y
    NSMutableDictionary *cardLimits;
    [cardLimits setObject:ageUnder18.text forKey:@"ageUnder18"];
    NSLog(@"Just set %@", [cardLimits objectForKey:@"ageUnder18"]); //returns NULL

//more code here
}
```

Why is that returning NULL?

Thanks in advance,
James

Comment: James, it's just not your lucky day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not initializing your variable. In fact, you're rather lucky that you aren't crashing outright on the `-setObject:forKey:` line. Your `cardLimits` variable currently holds garbage memory, i.e. whatever was on the stack at the address that the variable occupies. You need to use

```
NSMutableDictionary *cardLimits = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
```

Note that the Static Analyzer should be able to catch this for you.

Comment: I don't think James is lucky a crash doesn't happen since his pointer should be nil by default and passing a message to nil is always a no-op.  However, I agree with the rest of your answer.

Comment: @Sam: Stack variables are not implicitly nilled, except in ARC. You may be thinking about ivars, which are always nilled on object allocation.

Comment: +1 Just tried it, looks like you are right.  Stack variables are indeed not implicitly nilled (except in ARC - didn't try that part, but I trust ya).  Now I completely agree with your answer and disagree with my own!  I'll remove my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are not allocating cardLimits at any time. You need:

```
 NSMutableDictionary *cardLimits = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't initializing a `NSMutableDictionary`.